# Increasing memory through terminal in linux through "-XX:PermSize=192m -XX:MaxPermSize=2g -Xms2g -Xmx2g"

Tags: java, linux, memory, memory-management

I am running java developer IDE and in a process of trouble shooting a module . For this i have increased the logging memory of the tool, Now when logging it error is coming on console as

```
Uncaught exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

i am using below command for increasing memory

```
"-XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=192m -XX:MaxPermSize=2g -Xms2g -Xmx2g"
```

earlier it is

```
"-XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=192m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
```

my system memory is 16 GB through the command cat /proc/meminfo
but the system free memory is less than 1 GB when exception

```
Uncaught exception
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

is coming , I have allocated maximum memory to be utilized as 2gb

```
 -XX:MaxPermSize=2g
```

but it is occupying approximately all available memory.

Do not know whether this command is help full or not whether could i assign more memory like below command

```
"-XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=192m -XX:MaxPermSize=10g -Xms10g -Xmx10g"
```

increasing it to 10g will be good or not , or is there any problem with my command.

Comment: Why do you allocate so much to the permanent space? Do you understand what it is?

Comment: my IDE is hanging again and again so that it may not hang again i  want to increase the memory to 10g

Comment: You should first make sure that this is really a memory/GC problem. Have you tried running with `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`?

Comment: no i will try with it .

Comment: @SarthAk You probably need more heap space, not more permanent space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m to control your heap size (1024m is only for demonstration, the exact number depends your system memory). Setting minimum and maximum heap size to the same is usually a best practice since JVM doesn't have to increase heap size at runtime